# Is there an easy way to create a FreeBSD rc script?

Tags: shell-script, freebsd, startup, daemon, jails

I have a FreeBSD jail in which I run a server using the command:

```
/usr/sbin/daemon /path/to/script.py
```

At the moment I have to run this command every time I restart the machine and the jail starts. I'd like to have this command started from `/etc/rc`. Is there an easy way to create a FreeBSD rc script for a `daemon` command?

---

**UPDATE:** I read through [this BSD documentation about rc scripts](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/rc-scripting/rcng-daemon.html), and from that I created the following script in `/etc/rc.d/pytivo`:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.subr

name=pytivo
rcvar=pytivo_enable
procname="/usr/local/pytivo/pyTivo.py"

command="/usr/sbin/daemon -u jnet $procname"

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

This works to start the python script I am wanting as a daemon when the jail starts... (given `pytivo_enable="YES"` is in `/etc/rc.conf`) but the rc script doesn't know if the daemon is running (it thinks it isn't when it is) and it gives a warning when I try to start it:

```
[root@meryl /home/jnet]# /etc/rc.d/pytivo start
[: /usr/sbin/daemon: unexpected operator
Starting pytivo.
[root@meryl /home/jnet]#
```

So it's *close*, and it *works*, but I feel like I should be able to get better functionality than this.

Comment: You need to put this script somewhere(Can't remember now) and put a line `XX_enable="YES"` in /etc/rc.conf to make it auto start. Start by finding existing scripts

Comment: I'm looking for an easy way to create the script... Is there a good script I can copy and reuse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`command` should not contain multiple words. This is the cause of the `[` error you see. You should set any flags separately.

Also, you should use `pytivo_user` to set the running uid, and not `daemon -u`. See the [rc.subr(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.subr&sektion=8) man page for all these magic variables.

Also, you should let the rc subsystem know that pytivo is a Python script so that it can find the process when it checks to see if it's running.

Finally, you should use the idiomatic `set_rcvar` for `rcvar`.

Something like this (I'm not sure this is the right Python path):

```
#!/bin/sh

# REQUIRE: LOGIN

. /etc/rc.subr

name=pytivo
rcvar=`set_rcvar`
command=/usr/local/pytivo/pyTivo.py
command_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
pytivo_user=jnet
start_cmd="/usr/sbin/daemon -u $pytivo_user $command"

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

Comment: The problem is that `usr/local/pytivo/pyTivo.py` *doesn't daemonize*, therefore without calling `/usr/bin/daemon` I will just get the command running in the forground when I run `/etc/rc.d/pytivo start`

Comment: However this does correct the `status` and `stop` commands!

Comment: Oh, the script doesn't daemonize? I think the easiest fix is to set `start_cmd` before calling `load_rc_config`: `start_cmd="/usr/sbin/daemon -u $pytivo_user $command"`

Comment: This had the magic I needed to get my script running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an rc-script, you could use just /etc/rc.local.

For your rc script you are missing dependenct comments, at least a line

```
# REQUIRE: LOGIN
```

should help, that it is run at the right time.

You also may need to define a pidfile

```
pytivo_pidfile="/path/to/your/pidfile"
```

Comment: I was hopeful this would help, but it doesn't. I still get `: /usr/sbin/daemon: unexpected operator` and my rc script still doesn't know if the script is actually running.

Comment: you could try to invoke the script with -x to see which command fails