# Make "local startup" or "service start/enabled filebeat" command on pfSense (FreeBSD)

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I just install the filebeat port v6.8.7 on pfSense 2.4.5 box (freeBSD 13). After that I want to start filebeat service with

```
service start filebeat
```

but it throw error:

```
start does not exist in /etc/rc.d or the local startup
directories (/usr/local/etc/rc.d), or is not executable
```

Anyone know hot to make this file work/make filebeat work please share with me the solution. I'm new to freeBSD
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 3):

The `service` command requires that the filebeat service installed a `rc` script to be able to start anything. The fist thing I notice is that your syntax is wrong - you need the service name before the command.

```
service filebeat start
```

This is why you get the error that `start` does not exist.

If you get a similar error with `service filebeat start` then examine the contents of the folder `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`. The port should have installed a script at that location.

If the port have not made a service/rc script for you - then you can do it yourself. See...

- [Practical rc.d scripting in BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/index.html)
- [Is there an easy way to create a FreeBSD rc script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50478/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-freebsd-rc-script)